# How to solve this with a lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

This is the question:

" Write a program that extracts from a text all words which are palindromes, such as ABBA", "lamal", "exe". "

And this is my code:

```
public static List<string> FindPalindromes()
    {
        string text = String.Empty;
        Console.Write("Enter the text:\n\t");
        text = Console.ReadLine();

        List<string> answer = new List<string>();

        string[] words = text.Split('.', ',', ' ', ':', '/', '\\', '"', ';');
        foreach(string word in words.Where(
                (string x) =>
                {
                    if(String.Equals(x, x.Reverse()))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
            ))
            answer.Add(word);

        return answer;
    }
```

Now I think that it would more tidy if I separated the logic in the where method into a separate method that returns a Boolean and checks if a single word is a palindrome. But I want to try using a lambda.

Anyhow, this code does not return anything. I suspect the problem is in the if conditional.

Comment: FYI, you can simplify the lambda to `x => String.Equals(x, x.Reverse())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x.Reverse()` is calling `Enumerable.Reverse()`, which will return you an `IEnumerable<char>` - *not* a string. That's why `Equals` is never returning `true`. Here's an alternative:

```
char[] chars = x.ToCharArray();
Array.Reverse(chars);
return x == new string(chars);
```

Or you could just call `string.Join` or `string.Concat` on the reversed sequence of characters - horribly inefficient, but it'll get the job done in a single expression, allowing you to replace everything from the `foreach` onwards by:

```
return words.Where(x => x == string.Concat(x.Reverse())
            .ToList();
```

Much cleaner :) Any time you find yourself repeatedly adding to a list, consider using a query and `ToList()`. You'd already got the filtering part, you just needed to use `ToList()` to get rid of the `foreach` loop.

Likewise, any time you find yourself with:

```
if (condition)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

... **strongly** consider refactoring to:

```
return condition;
```

Comment: `string.Concat(x.Reverse())` is even more concise than `Join` ;)

Comment: Totally unrelated, but I tend to use `string.Empty` rather than `""`. Seeing now that you use `""` makes me wonder if I should quit programming forever in shame and utter defeat.

Comment: `""` and `string.Empty` are identical.  It's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @recursive: *Nearly* identical. `""` is a compile-time constant; `string.Empty` isn't. There's a question somewhere about it...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, problem is in your `String.Equals` call. `x.Reverse` returns an `IEnumerable<char>` which will never be equal to your string.  try:

```
if(String.Equals(x, new string(x.Reverse().ToArray()))
```

Comment: `new string` doesn't have an overload that takes `IEnumerable<char>`

Answer (score 2):

You code can be changed to:

```
answer = words.Where(x => String.Join("", x.Reverse()) == x).ToList();
```

Comment: @Servy: `String.Join` gained new overloads in .NET 4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Well it's not using that overload... it's using `Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)`

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, I was on the wrong machine at the time.  Still, it's not really the appropriate tool for the job at all.

Comment: I would use `string.Concat` instead of `string.Join` with an empty separator.

Comment: @recursive definitely, there is no sense to use `Join` here

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You are soo kind, thanks for editing my ~25 answer.

Answer (score 1):

`x.Reverse` isn't a string, it's an `IEnumerable<char>`.  You need to convert that sequence of characters back to a string to compare it with another string.  That, or use a comparison tool that can compare two *sequences* rather than two *strings*, since you don't have a string:

```
return words.Where(word => word.SequenceEqual(word.Reverse()))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite it like this:

```
public static List<string> FindPalindromes() {
    Console.Write("Enter the text:\n\t");
    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] words = text.Split('.', ',', ' ', ':', '/', '\\', '"', ';');

    return words.Where(word => word.Reverse().SequenceEqual(word)).ToList();
}
```

This makes a number of changes.

1. It doesn't use an intermediate `List` to store results.  This is unnecessary with linq.
2. It doesn't use an `if` statement.  This is unncessary since the only purpose of it is to return true or false, which is a value you already have in the `if` condition.
3. It corrects the reversal comparison.  It uses `.SequenceEqual` which correctly compares the characters in both sequences.